# Set Multiple properties to an edge in titan using Java API

Tags: java, titan

I want to set multiple properties to the same edge.

```
tialVertex.addEdge("temp",headVertex).setProperty("key1", "value1");
```

The above command sets only one key-value pair. If I use it again, lets say for  "key2","value2", it will create another edge with the same label(temp) between same vertex instead of appending key-value pair to the edge.

To put together I want one edge having to or more properties(**"key1":"value1"** , **"key1":"value1"**....)

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using Gremlin, Titan (and the Blueprints API) does not allow for a multi-setter for properties.  Note that this is not true in Gremlin Groovy:

```
tialVertex.addEdge("temp",headVertex, [key1:"value1",key2:"value2"])
```

there are [helper methods](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.4.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/ElementHelper.html#setProperties%28com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Element,%20java.lang.Object...%29) in Blueprints that you might find useful:

```
ElementHelper.setProperties(tialVertex.addEdge("temp",headVertex), "key1","value1","key2","value2")
```

Note that this approach offers no additional performance enhancements on insert.  And of course, you could always just assign the `Edge` to a variable and `setProperty` from there:

```
Edge e = tialVertex.addEdge("temp",headVertex);
e.setProperty("key1","value1");
e.setProperty("key2","value2");
```